# Populating a listbox in c#

Tags: c#, excel, listbox

I have a listbox and I manage to bind the Excel worksheet to the list box (after hours of researching on the Internet).

Now I need to read the values from the sheet into the listbox, but unable to locate any suitable solution.

This is what I have done so far:-

```
private void LoadExcelSheet(string path, int sheet){
   _Application excel = new Excel.Application();
   Workbook wb;
   Worksheet ws;

   int row = 0;
   int col = 0;

   wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(path);
   ws = wb.Worksheets[sheet];

   for (row = 1; row < 10; row++){
      for (col = 1; col < 6; col++){
         listBox1.Items.Add(ws.Cells[row, col].Value2);
      }
   }
 }
//------------------ end of LoadExcelSheet---------------------------

 this only display 1 row with each item of data on top of each other eg:-

aaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbb 
cccccccc
dddddddd

instead of: aaaaaaaa bbbbbbbb cccccccc dddddddd
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Well, duh.  A listbox only has 1 dimension, but the worksheet has 2.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your for loops, try this:

```
for (var row = 1; row < 10; row++) 
{
     string r = "";
     for (var col = 1; col < 6; col++)
     {
         r += " " + ws.Cells[row, col].Value2;
     }
     listBox1.Items.Add(r.Trim());
}
```

Comment: Keith... thanks for your support.... however, I tried David's solution. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You are populating the list box inside a loop containing the columns, try something like

```
for (row = 1; row < 10; row++){
    string a = "";
    for (col = 1; col < 6; col++){
        a += ws.Cells[row, col].Value2+" ";
     }
     listBox1.Items.Add(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's split the problem

1. Data collection
2. Collected data representation

Data collection (with a help of *Linq*):

```
 using System.Linq;

 ...  

 string[] data = Enumerable
   .Range(1, 9)                                   // 9 rows, starting from 1
   .Select(row => string.Join(" ", Enumerable     // cols are joined with space
      .Range(1, 5)                                // 5 columns in each row
      .Select(col => ws.Cells[row, col].Value2)))
   .ToArray();
```

And `data` representation (as `ListBox` items):

```
 listBox1.Items.AddRange(data);
```